# The vector doesn't push_back the integer

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote a simple program to generate prime numbers. The prime number printed out nicely. I also tried to put each prime number in a vector for further processing, but somehow the numbers does't seem to go into (i.e. push_back) the vector as it prints out strange numbers instead of the prime numbers. In short, the entire program works fine, only the vector has problem. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int NUM = 300;

int main()
{
    int i, j ;
    int counter = 0;
    bool arr[NUM] = {false}; //false == 0
    vector<int> aVector;

    ...


    cout << "\nNumber of prime numbers is " << counter << endl;

    for (j=0; j<aVector.size() ; j++)
    {
        cout << "aVector[" << j << "] is " << aVector[j] << endl;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is `NUM` defined?

Comment: You should use iterators (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) to loop over your vector so you are sure not to go out of bounds.

Comment: You omitted a crucial step between the thought "doesn't seem to work" and posting to the internet: You did not *prove* that this part *actually* is what is not working, by reducing your example to *just that specific part*. You would have realized that `push_back()` is not the problem. This is an essential debugging skill, and also the reason why we ask for [minimal, complete, verifyable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) examples. It just makes answering so much easier, if you don't realize your mistake *before* posting at all.

Comment: Aside from the out-of-bounds accesses (which you could verify yourself by replacing `bool arr[NUM] = { false };` with `std::vector<bool> arr( NUM, false );` and all occurences of `[...]` with the range-checking `.at(...)`) --- I cannot bring the code to reproduce your output on either GCC 4.8 / Linux, GCC 4.9 / Cygwin, or MSVC 2010. All three produce the expected output (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29), not what you posted. Voting to close.

Comment: DevSolar - I have already mentioned that the problem is the vector.  Other than that, everything works fine. All prime number prints out nicely.

Comment: DevSolar - the prime number output comes out nicely :   2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    31    37   41    43    47    53    59    61    67    71    73    79    83    89    97 101   103   107   109   113   127   131   137   139   149   151   157   163 167   173   179   181   191   193   197   199   211   223   227   229   233  239   241   251   257   263   269   271   277   281   283   293   300

Comment: DevSolar - your explanation doesn't stick with the problem.

Comment: There is no problem with the vector, but there is still a problem with the array. You are *still* accessing out-of-bounds memory, since you are ignoring the fact that **array indices start at zero**. `bool arr[NUM]` contains the `bool` objects `arr[0]` through `arr[ NUM - 1 ]`, so your code (looping to `NUM + 1`) invokes undefined behaviour. Once that is fixed, the program works fine on the compilers I mentioned above, and I *seriously* doubt you've found a bug in CodeBlocks. BTW, your comment `// false == 1` doesn't make sense....

Comment: "bool arr[NUM] contains the bool objects" doesn't make sense. "looping to NUM + 1" nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @DevSolar -  "You omitted a crucial step between the thought "doesn't seem to work" and posting to the internet"  you should have studied psychology instead.  "You did not prove that this part actually is what is not working"  If ones know and can prove what went wrong, I don't think they need StackOverflow. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MLAC: You came to SO looking for people with more experience than you to help with your problem. You found them. Now all you have to do is listen to them. Note that the answer by Андрей Беньковский (whom you call "my hero!" is essentially what I wrote above.

Comment: The code still contains the same bug I pointed out. `NUM+1` needs to be replaced by `NUM` in all places.

Comment: @DevSolar - If you look at my comments, I did discuss and listen to other people who gave me constructive and practical suggestions. If you had given me suggestions instead of criticizing, I'd have listened to you.

Comment: @M.M - why NUM+1 is no good?  You also said earlier "i <= NUM" is not good.  But I think i <= NUM is just fine as many people do that with Java. The textbook says it's legal too.  I have to include NUM because it is the last number I have to check whether it is prime or not.  So, if i don't put "i <= NUM", then I have to put "i<NUM+1".  You said no but you didn't give me any suggestion or explanation.

Comment: @MLAC: In C and C++, an array declared as `bool arr[NUM]` will have `NUM` elements, which can be accessed as `arr[0]` to `arr[ NUM - 1 ]`. Accessing the (non-existent) `arr[NUM]` is undefined behaviour, breaking your program. That is why a loop to `<= NUM` or `< NUM + 1` is a bug. And that is *exactly* what *several* people have been telling you all along (including the suggestion on how to use a `vector` and the range-checking access method `.at()` instead to get an out-of-bounds exception like Java does), *but you are not listening*.

Comment: @ DevSolar - I got what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to be ashamed of your code, however. We all make mistakes. If you delete the code, all the answers here become meaningless. It would be better to mark one of the answers as "correct".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) pointed out, in a number of places in your code you are trying to get and set values from outside the boundary of the `arr` array. This is undefined behaviour in C++. Once you invoke an undefined behavior **anything** can happen - the behavior of your **entire**  program (not only the line containing the error) is unpredictable. Writing outside the boundary of a static array usually results in overwriting other variables.

It looks like your program overwrites the internal data of `aVector`, replacing it's pointer a dynamically allocated array with something else. No wonder it than prints "random junk" - the vector now thinks it's contents are in a different location in the memory.

As a rule of thumb: [Simple C [] arrays are evil](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#arrays-are-evil), use vectors instead:
`vector<bool> arr(NUM, false)`. To access an element use: `arr.at(some_index)`. This will throw an exception if `some_index` is outside of the vector boundaries. Note that `arr[some_index]` doesn't perform a boundary check even if you use  vectors and therefore can cause an undefined behaviour too.

Comment: What I said, but +1 for putting it into clearer words and welcome to StackOverflow. ;-)

Comment: @Андрей Беньковский - Thanks for your constructive suggestion!! you are my hero. It works now... I agree with you that array in c/c++ is evil.

Comment: `vector<bool>` is even more evil than C-style arrays

Comment: @M.M. you have not been giving any solution. Андрей Беньковский's suggestion using vector<bool> is a very good idea.

Comment: @ M.M - i do not agree. Vector is better than array if the size of array is not fixed.

Comment: @MLAC I posted a solution already, including proof that it works

Comment: @M.M nope. vector<bool> is less evil than C arrays. 1. A cryptic compile time error is still better than an even more cryptic, inconsistent run time error that can make any part of your code misbehave in any possible and impossible way. 2. Vectors handle resizing and RAII properly, they have efficient move and swap operations. You'd effectively have to reimplement a vector to get all this using C arrays. 3. Until you start trying to get a memory address of an element (aka pointer or reference), vector<bool> mostly follows the same semantics other vectors do.

Comment: 4. It can be very confusing the first time you see the compiler error mentioned above and it's very counterintuitive, but once you are aware of this stl feature there are numerous ways of dealing with it (`vector<bool>::reference`, `vector<char>`, `deque<bool>`...).

Comment: @Андрей Беньковский  I totally agree with you.  Vectors use a dynamically allocated array to store their elements.  Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @MLAC: What those two are discussing is that [`vector<bool>` is a special case](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) that not necessarily behaves like a "real" `vector<>` in all cases. You need to be aware of that.

Comment: @M.M to clarify: I'm not saying that vector<bool> is easy to use and/or intuitive. I'm saying that it's better (safer, easier to debug, has more functionality) than bool[].

Comment: @DevSolar Technically you are supposed to always use `collection::iterator` `collection::reference` `collection::pointer` etc. The assumption that `vector<T>::pointer` is `T*` works in most simple cases, but is incompatible with `vector<bool>` and with [custom allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator). P.S. I usually make this assumption unless there is a good reason to do extra work (i.e. custom allocators are actually used in the project).

Answer (score 6):

Your code accesses out of bounds of `arr`. Arrays are zero-indexed in C++.

`for (i = 2; i<=NUM; i++)` should be: `for (i = 2; i<NUM; i++)`

`for (j = 1; j <= NUM/i; j++)` should be: `for (j = 1; j * i < NUM; j++)`

After applying these fixes, your code [appears to work for me](http://ideone.com/a77lS2).   I removed the `if (i` check as it's redundant.

Comment: That part works just fine. I don't see your suggestions would make any difference.

Comment: I've changed the part you suggested, but the vector still doesn't  work.

Comment: @MLAC Update your question with the exact code, including my fixes, that apparently doesn't work. Make sure you verify that running the *exact* code you post in your question causes the problem. I saw you hastily editing before.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple quick fix. looping to the end of the vector.

```
for (j=0; j<aVector.size() && j < 6; j++){
        cout << "aVector[" << j << "] is " << aVector[j] << endl;
}
```

------------------------the complete code that i tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
#define NUM 100
int main()
{
    int i, j ;
    int counter = 0;
    bool arr[NUM] = {false}; //false == 1
    vector<int> aVector;

    for (i = 2; i<=NUM; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 0)
        {
            cout << setw(6) << i ; //i is a prime number

            /****doesn't seem to work****/
            aVector.push_back(i);  //fill the vector with prime numbers
            counter++;

            if (i <= NUM/2)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= NUM/i; j++)
                {
                    arr[i*j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\nNumber of prime numbers is " << counter << endl;

    /*** it prints out strange numbers ******/
    for (j=0; j<aVector.size() && j < 6 ; j++){
        cout << "aVector[" << j << "] is " << aVector.at(j) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I just want the first six elements??

Comment: @MLAC please check it now.. it'll work for first 6 elements

Comment: @MLAC and if the elements are lesser it'll only provide the elements currently in the vector

Comment: -  I got the following output:

Comment: aVector[0] is 1177830227
aVector[1] is 1348218928
aVector[2] is 1769105761
aVector[3] is 1917871982
aVector[4] is 1936026985
aVector[5] is 1852400220
aVector[6] is 1650803804
aVector[7] is 1348233077
aVector[8] is 1769105761
aVector[9] is 1917871982
aVector[10] is 1936026985 ......

Comment: @MLAC check what I have tried. and try to compile it on you machine or [ideone](https://ideone.com/RsjarS)

Comment: still not working.  output:  aVector[0] is 1177830227
aVector[1] is 1348218928
aVector[2] is 1769105761
aVector[3] is 1917871982
aVector[4] is 1936026985
aVector[5] is 1852400220

Comment: @MLAC what is your OS and IDE or compiler?

Comment: It's CodeBlocks 13.12 on Windows 10

Comment: @MLAC and the values of `i` in statement `cout << setw(6) << i ;` printed correctly?

Comment: I did another program with vector with large data, and it works just fine.... not sure why it doesn't seem to work this time...

Comment: yes, all the i are printed out correctly....  it is very strange that "i" comes out good, but it somehow doesn't go into the vector...

Comment: @MLAC Please copy and paste the code from my answer into the codeblock and try compiling it.